# $this keyword in view in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to understand how `$this->load->view()` works *inside* of a view file in CodeIgniter.

The core/Controller.php is calling core/Loader.php which then calls _ci_load() which in turn does an `include('/path/to/view');`

Shouldn't `$this` refer to the Loader class at that point? How is `$this` referring to the controller?

By my understanding, you should have to call $this->view() inside of a view file. Not $this->load->view() because the load() function is not accessible inside of the Loader. It's a class variable of the Controller base class. i.e, `$this->load =& load_class('Loader');`

Please note: I'm trying to understand the CodeIgniter internals. I know perfectly well how to embed view files in other view files as a CodeIgniter *user*. Please do not leave answers explaining how to *use* $this->load().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last time I checked, `$this` was of class `CI_Loader`, try `var_dump($this);` inside a view.

---

Check out:

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Controller.php

`is_loaded();` returns an array with the already loaded classnames and their aliases from the main container.

`$this->load` is then an instance of `CI_Loader` inside the controller.

---

Check:

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php

Line 778

Comment: But there is no load() function in CI_Loader. So how does `$this->load->view()` work?

Comment: Inherited from extended class perhaps?

Comment: Loader uses `_ci_load_class();` and `_ci_load();`. Overloads.

Comment: Could you explain how that kind of overloading works? How does $this->load() get turned into $this->_ci_load_class()?

Comment: Right. I understand that part. When you call $this->load->view() in a View $this should now be an instance of CI_Loader not CI_Controller. Inside of the view, how does calling $this->load() work?

Comment: `$this->load =& load_class('Loader', 'core');` is in the Controller class. `$this->load` makes sense if you're in a Controller.  I don't understand how that works in a View file, when $this refers to the Loader class, not the Controller class.

Comment: OK I edited my answer again. You should really read the source, it's all there.

Answer (score 5):

To simplify the understanding of what `$this` refers to in a view, since a view is "loaded" by a controller method, the view is still run in the same scope as that method, meaning `$this` can have a different context depending on which class loaded it.

For example:

```
class Controller1 extends CI_Controller {}
```

In any view file loaded in this example controller, `$this` refers specifically to the `Controller1` class, which can access `CI_Controller` public and protected properties/methods as well (like the Loader or Input classes, which are assigned to the `load` and `input` properties of CI_Controller) since it *extends* that class.

Controllers are still just plain old PHP classes. If I were to do this:

```
class Controller1 extends CI_Controller {
    $this->foobar = 'Hello';
}
class Controller2 extends CI_Controller {
    $this->foobar = 'World';
}
```

...if we load the *same view file* in any method of either of these controllers, using `$this->foobar` in that view file will return a different value.