# How to implement pagination in my searchform codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, search, pagination

I have a search function in my codeigniter project.

the search uses a join for searching in multiple tables.
now is my question: How do i add pagination to that searchform so it shows 5 results on one page.

### My searchfunction

```
function searchresults()
{
    $match = $this->input->post('search');
    $data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match);
    $this->load->view('views/header');
    $this->load->view('views/searchresults', $data);
    $this->load->view('views/footer');
    $data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->bedrijven_tags();
}
```

### My searchview

```
<form name="input" action="searchresults" method="post">
<input type="search" placeholder="Zoeken..." name="search">

<input type="submit" value="Zoeken">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

<br /><br />

<form method="link" action="<?php echo base_url('home/bedrijven')?>">
<input type="submit" value="Bedrijven">

</form>
```

### What i've tried:

```
    function searchresults()
    {
        $match = $this->input->post('search');
        $data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match);
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = base_url();
        $config['total_rows'] = 10;
        $config['per_page'] = 5;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
        $this->load->view('views/header');
        $this->load->view('views/searchresults', $data);
        $this->load->view('views/footer');
        $data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->bedrijven_tags();
    }
```

in my views: `echo $this->pagination->create_links();`

But it does not work.

Hope someone can help me :)

Thanks.

Comment: Please add your model to the question.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Is the pagination displaying? The `pagination` library is only a helper for **displaying** the pagination. I think you are missing to adjust the query. If this is the case I can post an answer on how I would do that.

Comment: it does not display at all. that's the strange thing. i will post my model tommorrow i have to go now.

Comment: Total rows config should be coming from your search functions (it's the number of matched results), for search to work well with codeigniter, you'll need to use get method instead of post and setup the pagination to use the get method too instead of segements.

Answer (score 0):

First, `$this` inside the view is not the same as inside the controller. (Compare to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283359/this-keyword-in-view-in-codeigniter).) I'd pass the pagination like this:

```
(Controller)
...
$data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
...
$this->load->view('views/searchresults', $data);

(View)
<?php echo $pagination; ?>
```

Secondly, remember that the `pagination` library is only a helper for displaying the pagination. You have to adjust the database query by yourself, e.g.

```
(Controller)
$skip_entries = $this->uri->segment(2); // or whatever segment it's for you
$this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match, $skip_entries);

(Model)
function get_search($search, $skip_entries)
{  
    ...
    $this->db->limit(5, $skip_entries);
    ...
}
```

Comment: `$this` is accessible inside views, but it isn't the same as `$this` in a controller or model. It should really only be used for loading sub-views.

Comment: i implemented this into my app but no pagination is shown. i got this strange behavior yesterday too.

Answer (score 0):

want to switch to the JS pagination plugin here is the link
[http://www.datatables.net/]
if you just wanted to show the nest data without any altercation then i think this could help.

Comment: thanks, but i think i stick with the codeigniter pagination library :)